# Avoid double hashing in HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

My keys are already the (blake3) hashes of my values.

How can avoid wasteful re-hashing of these keys when storing the values in a HashMap?

Comment: Define a custom [Hasher](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hasher.html) which treats the input data as random enough, and just mixes it into the hash state. You will need some form of re-compression still as the hashmap works with a u64 hash, but I'd assume XOR-ing every 64 bytes from the input into the output would do.

Comment: You can use the [nohash-hasher crate](https://crates.io/crates/nohash-hasher).

Comment: It's a bad idea to have prehashed values, because hash tables should be free to randomize the hash function they use internally to have more efficient strategies; even if you waste time for hashing something that is already a hash, you gain efficiency in the strategy used by the underlying hash table.

Comment: @jthulhu I don't think that's true, at least not for this specific case. BLAKE3 is a cryptographic hash, so it's essentially random. And the default hash used by Rust for hasbrown isn't taylored in any way for the specific implementation.

Comment: My experience is that it is often much faster to use a faster hash than the default. Even the Rust compiler does that.

Comment: @SvenMarnach the question is not about whether the hash looks random enough, but rather whether the hash table is free to pick a new hash function at random at any point, because the currently used hash function behaves too poorly. Not every hash table scheme requires this, but the algorithmically more efficient ones do AFAIK, so if performance is an issue, I'd rather look for a hash table that does so rather than assuming keys are already "random enough" and trying to optimize based on that.

Comment: Typically, it's this kind of hash table schemes that have constant time lookup and deletion, as opposed to amortized constant time for most other hash tables.

Comment: @jthulhu Rust's hash table doesn't "pick" a particular hash function, it's written to work with any non-broken hash function. The default is chosen to satisfy DOS-resistance requirements, but you certainly can (and should) pick another one if your requirements are different.

Comment: It's not just that Rust's hash map _doesn't_ pick a different hasher if it feels it needs to. It _can't_ pick a different hasher, since the hasher is provided as a type parameter and is part of the interface.

Comment: Yes, and Rust's hash map is also known not to be very efficient, but works well in general purpose settings. My point is, if the hashmap is the bottleneck, and one wishes to optimize it, switching the hash used might be less efficient than simply using a hash map whose purpose is to be efficient. Basically, Rust's hashmap uses a generic hash map scheme where you don't assume you can swap out the hashing function. Using a well suited hash function in this case might improve performance, but I think performance would be improved even more by using a hashmap whose scheme uses hash swapping.

Comment: @jthulhu Rust's hashmap is known to be *very* efficient, it's the default hash function which is not, and the most common way to "fix" the hashmap's performances is to use a less expensive hash function (e.g. replace the default siphash by fxhash). The point of the hash function in a hashmap is to distribute entries in order to avoid conflicts, and a cryptographic hash pretty much distributes entries close to perfectly by definition and necessity, you do not need to rehash such a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom instance of `Hasher` which uses your BLAKE3 values, but you'll need to reduce them down to a `u64`, since that's the type that's used by the trait.  You can pick the first 64 bits or XOR the output together to produce a value.

However, be careful with this, because the default Rust hash table uses a secret key which randomizes the values to prevent attackers from providing many keys that all hash to the same bucket, causing pathological performance.  If your data are untrusted, then it's a security problem (DoS vulnerability) to use an unkeyed hash, even one that's cryptographically secure like BLAKE3.  Note that we assume that the attacker knows how your hash scheme works (because usually it's pretty easy to figure it out), so that isn't a valid defense to this sort of vulnerability.